# Connecting to SharePoint Online with certificate based authentication using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, x509certificate

Can we connect to SharePoint Online using certificate based authentication, using powershell? It is possible? Please share.

Below is my code snippet:
I'm using credentials now, can we use certificates for the same?

```
$username = "test@testenvironment.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "test123"
$secureStringPwd = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $secureStringPwd

$AdminCenterUrl = "https://testenvironment-admin.sharepoint.com"
$SiteUrl = "https://testenvironment.sharepoint.com/sites/SharepointDemo2"
$SiteTitle = "SharePoint Demo2"
$siteOwner = "test@testenvironment.onmicrosoft.com"

#Connect SharePoint Online
Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminCenterUrl -Credential $creds

#Poershell to create new communication site
New-SPOSite -Url $SiteUrl -Owner $SiteOwner -Template "STS#3"  -Title $SiteTitle -StorageQuota 1048
```

Comment: yes, this is possible. Depending on the resources you want to consume you can use the SP API or MS Graph. But since SO is about helping people with coding issues and I see no code or real programming related question I have nothing more to say about this subject

Comment: I've edited the post with the source code, could you please help?

Comment: does Connect-SPOService supports certificates based authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use PnP.PowerShell module. Use the Connect-PnPOnline cmdlet to connect.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/connect-pnponline?view=sharepoint-ps

Refer to Example 6.